# draggable up and down only in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm wondering how to restrict the movement of a draggable dom node to only up and down, and ideally, also restrict the maximum distance it can be dragged. Pure javascript answers please.

I'm hoping there is some way to interact with the native draggable stuff, rather than implementing it from scratch using mouse events.

Update: to be perfectly clear, when i say "restrict the movement" i'm talking about restricting the movement of the element being dragged. For example, if you click to drag and try dragging the dom node diagonally, I want the dom node to only change its y axis.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: A little imagination for ondragend... position relative only change the style.top

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere, that's a good idea. ondragend won't be the place for that tho, since i want to restrict it while you're dragging - not just on end.

Comment: @Cheruvian Can you post an answer so we're not discussing this in the main comment thread? Also, your idea won't work, and it seems that native draggable functionality doesn't allow modification of the element in-flight, so I'll almost definitely have to implement it from scratch. Please try a little harder next time to understand the question you're answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really wanted to do this with native drag events, but its starting to look like it just isn't possible. Falling back to mouse events, here's an example of something that's getting toward what I'm looking for:

```
<body>
    <div id='a'>
        <div>moose</div>
        <div>cat</div>
        <div>moosalo</div>
        <div>bang</div>
        <div>shank</div>
        <div>jeebus</div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>

</style>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('a')    

    for(var n=0; n<x.children.length; n++) {
        ;(function(c) {
            c.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
                console.log('dragstart')
                this.style.opacity = '.9'
                this.style.position = 'relative'

                if(c.style.top === "") {
                    var offsetStart = 0
                } else {
                    var offsetStart = parseInt(c.style.top.slice(0,-2))
                }

                var mouseStart = e.pageY
                var mousemoveHandler;
                document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler  = function(e) {
                    //this.style.opacity -= '.01'
                    c.style.top = offsetStart + e.pageY - mouseStart
                    console.log('drag: ', e.pageY, mouseStart, c.style.top)
                })
                document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
                    console.log('dragend')
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)
                })
            })
        })(x.children[n])
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, simply update the top but not eh left property of style element...

JS

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
 }

 function drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
 }

 function drop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
     var element = document.getElementById(data);

     var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
     var top = parseInt(style.top.replace("px"));
     var left = parseInt(style.left.replace("px"));

     top += ev.offsetY;
     left += ev.offsetX;

     element.style.top = top + "px";
     //No X-axis movement...
     //element.style.left = left + "px";
 }
```

CSS

```
#drag1
{
    background-color: black;
    height:69px;
    width:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#div1
{
    position:fixed;
    height:300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px red;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true" style="border:1px solid yellow" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: A. This doesn't work in firefox, B. This doesn't work correctly in Chrome (can't move it upwards for example). C. Since in my original question I wanted to be able to affect the movement of the *thing you're dragging* (ie the opaque copy of the target element), I would need some way to turn off the opaque copy and move the target element instead. How would I do that? As it stands, this answer does not answer my question.